# Get only selects with custom index

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I use simple scripts to fill sample data during manual testing of my web application. Mostly one-liners to fill textboxes.

But now I got a case where I got multiple dropdowns and I only need to fill those that are empty(same class, always different).
My current solution:

```js
$('#btn').click(function (){
  $('select').each(function (index) {
      if($(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 0) {
        $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 2);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ddl" id="target1">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
    <option value="3">OPTION 3</option>
</select>
<select class="ddl" id="target2">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">OPTION 3</option>
</select>

<button id="btn" class="btn">Fill empty boxes</button>
```

My question here is: Is there any selector for jQuery to get all dropdowns that got a selected index of 0(no selection)?
i.e. `$(".ddl[selectedIndex='0']").doStuff()`[does not work]?

I want to do the whole thing like `$(selector).prop('selectedIndex',2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain option selector, `:first-child` selector and `:selected` selector. This will return all first option elements that selected. Then traverse to select element using closest and set selectedIndex:

```
 $('option:first-child:selected').closest('select').prop('selectedIndex', 2);
```

```js
$('#btn').click(function (){
 $('option:first-child:selected').closest('select').prop('selectedIndex', 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ddl" id="target1">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
    <option value="3">OPTION 3</option>
</select>
<select class="ddl" id="target2">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">OPTION 3</option>
</select>
<select class="ddl" id="target3">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="2">OPTION 2</option>
    <option value="3">OPTION 3</option>
</select>

<button id="btn" class="btn">Fill empty boxes</button>
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `.closest('select')` instead of `.parent()`? Are there other places where `option` elements occur besides unter `select`s?

Comment: You can use parent here. as structure for option and select will not be changing. closest is useful in cases where DOM structure may change.